# How do I host both a web application and a REST api on localhost?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a SPA in React that communicates with my database through a ASP.NET Web Api that I also is building.

I host the React app with webpack on `localhost:8080`, and the web api defaults to `localhost:56963`.

When I try do a GET request from my React client, I get a wierd result. Instead of returning data from the webapi, **it returns the index.html content for the client.**
Here I call the webapi in my React client:

```
  componentWillMount(){
    // I expect this to return the resource with ID = 1.
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:56963/api/biologicalresource/1" ,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  }
```

console.log(result):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I run `wget "http://localhost:56963/api/biologicalresource/1"` in Powershell, I get the expected result:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Name":"Pontus","Skills":["HTML","C#","JavaScript","ReactJs","SCRUM","Web Api","REST"]}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Qzpcc2hhcmluZ2lzY2FyaW5nXFNlcnZlclxBUElcQVBJXGFwaVxiaW9sb2dpY2FscmVzb3VyY2VzXDE=?=
                    Content-Length: 88
                    Cache-Control: no-cache
                    Content-Typ...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Pragma, no-cache], [X-SourceFiles, =?UTF-8?B?Qzpcc2hhcmluZ2lzY2FyaW5nXFNlcnZlclxBUElcQVBJXGFwaVxiaW9sb2dpY2FscmVzb3VyY2VzXDE=?=], [Content-Length, 88], [Cache-Control
                    , no-cache]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 88
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cache: true , it's not a caching problem is it?,.. Have you tried without?

Comment: Yes, first I tried cache: false, but the result were wrong, so I changed it, same result.

Comment: If results are wrong with cache = false, they won't be right with cache = true..  I would suggest you make it work without the cache;

Comment: Sure, I just tried everything I could come up with. I have already switched back to cache : false. Perhaps I should edit this question to cache: false so that I do not draw attention to that detail.

Comment: Seen as the content returned is expected to be json, might be worth setting dataType='json' ,

Comment: Can you add your API code here.